# Code optimization for <select> tag and it's child tags

Tags: html, optimization, html-select

I need some code optimization regarding to my `<select>` tag.

I uses `<optgroup>` tag for categories and `<option>` for it's fields.

I have a 24 `<optgroup>` and 4-16 `<options>` per `<optgroup>` and 24 additional `<optgroup>` for the separator(to make it more readable).

And it looks like this:

```
<select class="" name="">
   <optgroup class="" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" label="">
      <option class="" value="">This is the default selected value</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="" label="Categories"> // up to 24 Categories
      <option class="" value="">Fields</option> // up to 16 Fields per Category
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="" label="_______________________&nbsp;"></optgroup> // separator
</select>
```

And the results are:

- File size is 31KB
- I will paste this in every page that needs this dropdown.

Question:

1. In what ways can I optimize this? Can you give me an example so that I will try it on my `localhost`.

Tried Solution:

- I tried to make a function for this and through `array()` problem is that when I use `xdebug` the `Self` is 40+, so I it will slow the response time in the production.

Additional Question for the answer recommended by `Prashanth Benny` which is to use `include_once` / `require_once`:

- How can I use the `selected` attribute dynamically? Ex. in URL or from Database comparison. How can I make it use the `selected` / `selected="selected"`?

Comment: which server language do you use?

Comment: I use php, pdo and html

Comment: store this piece of your code in a php file and render it whenever required..... wouldn't that help?

Comment: add the php tag too so that you would get some php help...! :)

Comment: @PrashanthBenny As I understand your comment, I tried that as I posted on my question **Tried Solution** the only problem is when I use the `xdebug` the `Self` is 40+, and I know that there is more to optimize it. If you have any idea/s let me know.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Oh! You mean using as `include_once` / `require_once` ?

Comment: yes.. include was the keyword i forgot.. you nailed it!
as told in the answer, minify would help you reduce your file size...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Load HTML async via Ajax request
- Store information as e.g. JSON data and build select field with a template engine on the client side
- Minify your code via HTMLMinifier (https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)

Comment: I only use php and html for now, but I'll make a study about your answer.